# write a c++program to convert a text file to html file

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of c++ and find this question and code online, was trying to make it ok to read not only the file he gave but also any txt file but it shows some problem and I have no idea how to fix

the text file is just like regular text file, not an HTML format txt file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

istream findParagraph(istream& is, string& word) 
{
    cout << "<br>" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    argv[1] = "The Republic, by Plato.txt";
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    char ch = 0;

    ofstream out("title.html");
    out << "<html>" << endl
        << "<head>" << endl
        << "<title>" << argv[1] << "</title>" << endl
        << "</head>" << endl
        << "<body>" << endl;

    typedef map<string, unsigned> dictionary_type;
    dictionary_type words;

    string word;
    while (findParagraph(infile, word))
        ++words[word];

    out << "</body>" << endl << "</html>";

} //end main

1>C:\Users\User\source\repos\txt2html\txt2html\txt2html.cpp(15,40): error C2440:  '=': cannot convert from 'const char [27]' to 'char *'
```

Comment: `argv[1] = "The Republic, by Plato.txt";` is not valid code. You should not be modifying the contents of the `argv` array at all. Either pass the desired filename as a real command line parameter to your app, or else use a separate variable to assign your test filename to, eg: `const char *filename; #ifndef _DEBUG filename = argv[1]; #else filename = "The Republic, by Plato.txt"; #endif`

Comment: Also `findParagraph` does not return anything.

Comment: i want to add the <br> in every paragraph

Comment: Help yourself by indenting your *own* code first. `<br>`'s will come naturally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is that specific to c++? I ask because the encompassed C standard(ex: C11 §5.1.2.2.1), allows modification of both `argv` and the strings pointed to by said-same, and I couldn't find (usually means "didn't search deep enough") any c++ specific restrictions.

Comment: You shouldn't use endl whenever you want a new line.  endl flushes the stream which you don't need to do so instead of using endl use `"\n"`

Comment: [[basic.start.main](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main)] I don't find anything prohibiting changing what argv[]'s points at, but remember an advice not to change that vector directly. The signature of the original `main` is flawed (in the absence of const) since what you could get in, could be const (in hardware) etc. It's just good form to not try to change it.

Comment: @WhozCraig you *may* be able to modify `argv` in C++, but you *shouldn't*. What you can't do in C++ is assign a `const char *` to a `char *` (since C++11, anyway). A string literal in C++ is a `const char []`, which decays into a `const char *`. That is what your compiler is complaining about when you try to store a string literal into `argv `

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Changing the values of the `main` `char**` wouldn't necessarily violate the constness of the `const char*`s pointed at originally, would it? It wouldn't even be a language violation (if I've understood it correctly) but ... bad form.

Answer (score 1):

You want a basic program that converts a textfile to a minimum html file. You can pass the filename of the text file as parameter to your program.

If the name of your executable program would be "convert", then you can invoke your program with `"convert input.txt"`

The first parameter that you enter on the command line will appear in argv[1], the 2nd in argv[2] and so on. argv[0] contains the name of the program itself.

So please adapt the handling of the argv parameter. By the way, you could also give the name of the output html file as additional parameter and user argv[2] as output file name. argc would then be 3.

After opening all files and checking for errors, we will first write initial header information to the output html file.

Then we use the `std::getline()` function to read the source file line by line, until it is completely read.

For each line we read, we will output the plain text to the html file and add a line break "< br >".

At the end, we write the closing tags and that's it.

Please see the attached skelleton example program, which you can use to develop your ideas further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Filename is parameter
    // Check if program has been invoked with on parameter
    if (argc == 2) {
        // Parameter is filename. Try to open the input text file
        std::ifstream textFile(argv[1]);
        // File could be opened 
        if (textFile) {
            // Now open the output file. Becuase, if this cannot be opened then no need to do further steps
            std::ofstream htmlFile("title.html");
            if (htmlFile) {
                // All files are open. Start to build the output
                // Start writing the header
                htmlFile << "<html>" << '\n' << "<head>" << '\n' <<"<title>" << argv[1] << "</title>" << '\n' << "</head>" << 
                    "<body>" << '\n';
                // Write the body
                // Frist read a complete line
                std::string line{};
                while (std::getline(textFile, line)) {
                    // Write the line and append a <br>
                    htmlFile << line << "<br>" << '\n';
                }
                // End of body
                htmlFile << "</body>" << '\n' << "</html>" << '\n';
            }
            else {
                // Error. HTML file could not be opend
                std::cerr << "Could not open output HTML file 'title.html'\n";
            }
        }
        else {
                // Error. input text file could not be opend
                std::cerr << "Could not open input text file '" << argv[1] << "'\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        // // Error, program has not been invoked correctly
        std::cerr << "Nof Filename given. Invoke this program ("<< argv[0] << ") with 'file name' as parameter\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```